# What's the difference between 'restriction on' and 'restriction of'?

Tags: prepositions, vocabulary

I have seen both forms in usage and couldn't work out the rule behind which preposition should be used in which context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rules about prepositions in English are admittedly messy and abound with apparent exceptions, but this one is straightforward.

**Restriction on** relates primarily to what person or thing is restricted.

> Since his release from jail, the only restriction on Joe is his requirement to see his parole officer every Tuesday at 8 a.m.

**Restriction of** relates primarily to the kind of restriction involved.

> Restriction of voting rights based on race is unconstitutional.

When both the object and type of restriction are involved, either preposition is acceptable.

> Now that Joe is no longer on parole, only the restriction on his voting rights remains

or

> Now that Joe is no longer on parole, only the restriction of his voting rights remains

both will work. Personally, I would use "on" if I wanted to draw attention to the fact that Joe is still subject to restrictions. I would use "of" if I wanted to draw attention to the kind of restrictions that Joe is still subject to. I qualify that with "personally" because I am not sure that all competent writers would agree with that subtlety.